# how to update datatable from managed bean jsf2 primefaces

Tags: ajax, forms, primefaces, datatable, updates

I want to update datatable from managedBean

this datatable is inside `p:tab` inside `p:tabView` inside `h:form` inside `p:dialog`

I tested this : but it is not updated :

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("tabView:lesarticles");
```

here is the dialog :

```
<p:dialog id="dialogc" modal="true" header="Nouveau Article"
    widgetVar="dlgc">
```

and here is the form(inside dialog ) :

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="formdialogc">
```

the tabView and datatable :

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" style="font-size: 14px;">

            <!-- ajouter elements -->
            <p:tab id="info_produit" title="Produits">



<p:dataTable id="lesarticles"  var="car" widgetVar="carsTable"
                    rowKey="#{car.ligneCommandeFournisseurId}"
                    value="#{commandeMB.commande.ligneCommandeFournisseurs}">
```

is there any way to resolve this problem

thank you in advance

Comment: If I interpret your question correctly you are asking how to update something on the browser from the server? It's not possible. Classical HTTP client/server communication does not work this way. Or maybe I misunderstood your question? If so could you re-phrase your question to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Well that should be simple:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{bean.getList}" update=":dataTableForm"/>
```

In the getList method I am assuming your refreshing the list which is shown in the `p:dataTable`:

```
<h:form id="dataTableForm">
    <p:dataTable/>
</h:form>
```

Just make sure that you are not nesting the forms seperate them and let them to do their own jobs.